# как правильно настроить wait для selenium? Java

Tags: java, selenium

На сайте [Яндекс_Маркета](https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--kholodilniki/71952/list?hid=15450081&how=dprice&local-offers-first=0&glfilter=13887626%3A13891805%2C13891866%2C13891871&page=2) загрузка элементов (результатов поиска) происходит по мере прокрутки страницы вниз. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы выполнение дальнейшего кода происходило только после загрузки всех элементов поиска на странице.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы код продолжал выполняться только после полной загрузки всех результатов поиска?  Сколько будет элементов выведено на конкретной странице - заранее не известно. Не знаю к какому элементу нужно привязаться и какой Expected_Condition использовать, чтобы правильно настроить wait.

Вот запись экрана, где видно, что я имею в виду:
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/kn6e_9FHiy4LTg

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, подходящие ответы можно найти по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium), где был задан вопрос:

> Как заставить Selenium 2.0 ждать загрузки страницы?

Все ответы цитировать не стану, но самый популярный из них:

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));

 wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)